# print the items in an arraylist row after row to get a particular index value in a column

Tags: java, mysql, arrays, json, arraylist

I have a table from the database that looks at this structure given below

```
id | col1  | col2
1  | item1 | item2
2  | item3 | item4
```

I have declared arraylist to hold the values as shown

```
ArrayList<String> dataList = new ArrayList<String>();
```

I have declared json array to hold arrays of result data from the database

```
JSONArray jArray = new JSONArray(result);
```

I am iterating through the json array and adding the item in an array list as shown

```
 for (int i = 0; i < jArray.length(); i++) {
     JSONObject json_data = jArray.getJSONObject(i);
     dataList.add(json_data.getString("col1"));
     dataList.add(json_data.getString("col2"));
```

}

How can I iterate through arraylist to get the items row by row so that i can data at a certain column by index position. Below is my attempt but it is not working as expected as it iterates through to print out everything

```
for (String line : dataList) {
System.out.println("this is the element in the arraylist>>>>> " +line);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may consider a list of `String` arrays, so that each entry would represent a row :

The list :

```
ArrayList<String[]> dataList = new ArrayList<String[]>();
```

Populating the list :

```
 for (int i = 0; i < jArray.length(); i++) {

     JSONObject json_data = jArray.getJSONObject(i);
     String[] strArray = new String[2];
     strArray[0] = json_data.getString("col1");
     strArray[1] = json_data.getString("col2");
     dataList.add(strArray);

 }
```

Using the list :

```
for (String[] line : dataList) {    

    System.out.println("Elements in the arraylist >>>>> " +line[0] + " " +line[1]);    

}
```

**Alternatively**, for a more generic way,  you could use an enumeration :

```
private enum Column {

        COL1("col1"), COL2("col2");

        private String name;

        public String getName() {
            return name;
        }

        Column(final String name) {
            this.name = name;
        }

}
```

Then populate the list :

```
 for (int i = 0; i < jArray.length(); i++) {

     JSONObject json_data = jArray.getJSONObject(i);
     String[] strArray = new String[Column.values().length];
     for (Column column : Column.values()){
        strArray[column.ordinal()] = json_data.getString(column.getName());
     }
     dataList.add(strArray);

 }
```

And have a display method that could filter on one or several columns :

```
private void displayColumns(Column ...columns){

    for(Column column : columns){

        //System.out.println(column.getName());

        for (String[] line : dataList) {    

            System.out.println( line[column.ordinal()]);    

        }
    }
}
```

You could call this method like e.g :

```
displayColumns(Column.COL1);
displayColumns(Column.COL2);
displayColumns(Column.COL1, Column.COL2);
```

Comment: dont know if you are closeby, how can I print all the items here to the console >>> 
dataListCol.add(strArrayCol);

Comment: Could you give an example of which output you expect, based on the table's content in your question ?

Comment: I need all the contents in col1 and col2

Comment: @parker : Last edit shows an alternate way, more generic and flexible .

Answer (score 1):

Try to create a Object to hold your values like this:

```
public class ObjectWrapper {
    private String col1;
    private String col2;
    // getter and setters;
    public String toString(){
       return "col1: " + col1 + "col2: " + col2;
    }
}

ArrayList<ObjectWrapper> dataList = new ArrayList<ObjectWrapper>();
for (int i = 0; i < jArray.length(); i++) {
        JSONObject json_data = jArray.getJSONObject(i);
        ObjectWrapper obj = new ObjectWrapper();
        obj.setCol1(json_data.getString("col1")));
        obj.setCol2(json_data.getString("col2")));
        dataList.add(obj);
}

for (ObjectWrapper line : dataList) {
               System.out.println("this is the element in the arraylist>>>>> " +line);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

this is the easist way to do it

```
public Class A{
private int id;
private String col1;
private String col2;
@Override
public String toString(){
       return "Id: "+id+ " col1: " + col1 + " col2: " + col2;
    }
}
//Main Method
ArrayList<A> list=new Gson.fromJson(result,A.class);
for(A a:list)
System.out.println(a.toString());
```

OR

```
for(int i=0;i<list.size();i++)
System.out.println(list.get(i));
```